# Execution of code in order for some purpose in node js

Tags: node.js, express, synchronization

I have some scenario where I need to first save user, once user saved I need to bind users id (primary key of user table ) as forign key to users_details table.

So my logic is having two create operations. one to store user and second to store user details. but here second create operation is depend on result of first create operation.

but issue is that whenever I executing for first create its waiting to result and parallel executing some code.

I have separate file for separation of logic

1. To get connection

   ```
   var mysql = require("mysql");
   var connection = {};

   connection.getConnection = function(){

   var con = mysql.createConnection({
       host: "localhost",
       user: "root",
       password: "******",
       database: "*****"
   });

   con.connect(function(err){
       console.log("10");
       if(err){
           console.log('Error connecting to Db');
           return;
       }
       console.log('Connection established');
   });

   return con;
   }

   module.exports = connection;
   ```
2. For general CR operations

   ```
   var connection = require("./connection.js");
   var execute = {};

   execute.insertQuery = function(query, values){

   var result;

   // getting connection
   var con = connection.getConnection();

   // General insert query
   con.query(query, values, function(err,rows){
       if(err) throw err;

       console.log('Data inserted into table:\n');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));

      // Send the response body
      result = rows;
      console.log("Result========= " + result);
      return result;  
   });

   // conncetion close
   con.end(function(err) {
     // The connection is terminated gracefully
     // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
     // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
   });

   console.log("Result========= " + result);
   return result;
   }   

   module.exports = execute;
   ```
3. This is statement creation

   ```
   router.post('/registerUser', function(req,res){

   saveUser();

   function saveUser(){

       var selectQuery = 'select username from users where username = ?';
       var values = [username];

       var usernameUsed = execute.selectQuery(selectQuery, values);                

       if(usernameUsed){
           req.flash('error_msg', 'Username is not availble, Please use different username.');
           res.redirect('/users/register');
       }else{

           var users = 'INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)';
           var values = [username, password];

           var inserted = execute.insertQuery(users, values);

           if(inserted){

               var users_details = 'INSERT INTO users_details (firstname, lastname, email, users_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
               var data = [firstname, lastname, email, inserted.insertId];

               var result = execute.insertQuery(user_details, data);

               if(result){
                   req.flash('success_msg', 'Congratulations. You are registered sucessfully.');
                   res.setStatus = 200;
                   res.redirect('/users/login');
               }else{
                   req.flash('error_msg', 'Sorry something went wrong, We are looking into it.');
                   res.redirect('/users/register');
               }
           }else{
               req.flash('error_msg', 'Sorry something went wrong, We are looking into it 2.');
               res.redirect('/users/register');
           }
       }
   }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `waterfall` method of [async module](http://caolan.github.io/async/)

```
async.waterfall([
        function (next) {
execute.insertQuery(users, values,next);
},function(user_details,next){
    execute.insertQuery(user_details, data,next);

}
    ], function(err,user_details){
      if(!err){
      //do your stuff with result
      execute.insertQuery(user_details, data);
      //send response from here or you can call function here and send response from function defination  
    }
   })


   execute.insertQuery function(user,values,next){
   //if you get any error pass to callback
    next(err)

   //Do your stuff and after successfull result send result in next callback
   next(null,user_details);
   }


   execute.insertQuery function(user_dtails,data,next){
   //if you get any error pass to callback
    next(err)

   //Do your stuff and after successfull result send result in next callback
   next(null,user_details);
   }
```

***Note:*** If you need `data` value in second or third function you can make it reachable by yourself so that you don't get any error

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Please can you help me here to do it via waterfall

Comment: Sure, What you did so for and where you stuck?

Comment: you know i have some insert operations, here second insert operation parameters are first operation result. but node js is async that why second insert is not waiting to complete first one hete `inserted` is result of first insert and while executing second insert i have to ckeck `inserted` is null or not here its not waiting to complete first insert 'inserted' coming null but i want to wait second insert till completion of first

Comment: You have written 3rd statement in router you can't do it in waterfall

Comment: so what is option left

Comment: I didn't get any scenario where router call in the middle, on the contrary, we start from the router and send the response after doing manipulation.

Comment: my all js is in router only. few i configured and few i am using without configuration

Comment: Can you clean your code, show mention which functions have executed one by one?

Comment: var inserted = execute.insertQuery(users, values); // 1     var result = execute.insertQuery(user_details, data);  //2 var result = execute.insertQuery(user_details, data); // 3

Comment: I am assuming that you have this three method which prduce some results and you want to use that result in a synchronous way